# Removing locked items from Users/Login Items on OSX 10.7.3?

Tags: macos

My laptop was distributed by corporate IT. I have two items in my Login Items which cannot be hidden or removed. See screen shot...

Inside the /Library/Managed Preferences/juba/loginwindow.plist file I see reference to these two items. It is searching for a server which is of course not found unless I am connected to the corporate network. I work remotely and do not regularly connect to that network.

How can I remove these items?

Comment: Do you have administrator powers on your computer? If no, how you remove the items might be to contact corporate IT.

Comment: You forgot to attach the screenshot.

Comment: +1 Daniel Lawson.  If your account is managed, that means they manage whatever they want on it.  You need administrator access to override that.